# Banking interest Q

Tags: java, double, joptionpane, banking

Im trying to make a program that calculates the compound interest of an account with the principle,interest rate, and years. Im trying to do it with dialogs/ The program has the output the return on the invesment if the principle is left to accumulate.

Im stuck on the calculation part, please help

```
package firstAssignment;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class thinkingQuestion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//Banking program that asks user for the amount of money they wish to invest in a 
//compound interest account (principle), the interest rate (percent value) and the time frame (years).

    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

    String principle, interestVal, years;
    int newPrinciple,newYears;
    double total;

        principle=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much money would you like to invest?");

        interestVal=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's the interest rate?");   

        years=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many years?");

        //convert from String to integer

        newPrinciple=Integer.parseInt(principle);
        newYears=Integer.parseInt(years);

        double newInterestVal=Integer.parseInt(interestVal);

        total=JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE(newPrinciple*Math.pow(1+ newInterestVal, newYears), newYears);
```

Comment: I'm particularly stuck on the totaling part because it wont let me use the Interest formula for the question.

Comment: total= newPrinciple*Math.pow((1+newInterestVal), newYears);

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, total+"", "Total", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                                                      Also you have to input number of compounding periods, n. Here I have assumed n=1

Comment: Its showing an error towards converting the string to int, particularly line 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted somo variables you don't need, I think the main problem is on java syntax for show messages. Here you could see a tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InterestBanking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Banking program that asks user for the amount of money they wish to
        // invest in a
        // compound interest account (principle), the interest rate (percent
        // value) and the time frame (years).

        String principle, interestVal, years;
        float newPrinciple, newYears;

        principle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much money would you like to invest?");

        interestVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's the interest rate?");

        years = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many years?");

        // convert from String to integer

        newPrinciple = Float.parseFloat(principle);
        newYears = Float.parseFloat(years);

        double newInterestVal = Float.parseFloat(interestVal);

        //You could change your calculation here if this isn't the need formula
        double interest = newPrinciple * Math.pow(1 + newInterestVal, newYears);

        //you were assigning the result to a total variable. That's not neccesary
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Interest:" + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format(interest) + " In years: " + newYears);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its showing an error when testing it, it says its the converting the String to double or int lines.

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: eclipse kepler, my school wont let us use a higher version

Comment: On window menu go to preferences > java > compiler. Tell me which is the compiler compliance level

Comment: the compiler level is 1.4

Comment: Could you change it to a superior one? Preferable to 1.7 or 1.6

Comment: Says the samething when i changed it to 1.7

Comment: Do you get an Exception like: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10.0" or similiar? Could you paste it here please?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".10"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at firstAssignment.thinkingQuestion.main(thinkingQuestion.java:28)

Comment: You are trying to insert a float number, while the code is only prepared to take integers. Try writing only integer numbers on the input. If you want to take float numbers, let me check.

Comment: The code is adapted to take float numbers, you must check which variables really need to be float.

Comment: Sometimes some letters appear in the interest when i do a float value. How do i also make the decimal format to $

Comment: 1. If you refer that the results sometimes takes this form: 1.333121421474E7 or similiar, is beacuse the number is too big or too small and is expressed on Scientific notation (with exponentials) 2. The code is updated.

Comment: If you have more troubles please let me know. I hope the answer was useful for you, if it was please accept it.

Comment: I would like to make it so the percent i take is a decimal that way i dont get ant exponents and such. also in decimal format

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-numberformat-to-format-a-percent.html